# How much ram is on my computer?

Tags: mac, memory

OS X Yosemite

Version 10.10.5

Mac Mini (Late 2014)

Processor 2.6 GHz Intel Core i5

Memory 8 GB 1600 MHz DDR3

Graphics Intel Iris 1536 MB

Answer (score 5):

RAM means Random Access Memory. 
You have 8 gigabytes of RAM (8 GB).

Answer (score 3):

Your RAM is called **Memory** in the specs you provided.

Answer: 8 GB